# HighCharts menu de exportação cortando

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Menu de exportação do highcharts]

Itens do menu de exportação do highcharts está cortando, alguem sabe como corrigir este problema? E se o highcharts tem algo nativo pra isso?

Comment: Tenta adicionar esse estilo ao seu código: #raphael-paper-10 ~ div {z-index: 9999 !important}, provavelmente o elemento que está escondendo ali ta gerando um z-index maior que o elemento do menu.

Comment: Não deu certo amigo, obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: Eu que bobeei, essa é pro fusionCharts, pro highcharts é isso acredito: ".highcharts-contextmenu {z-index:9999 !important}", ai depois você inspeciona o elemento que tem ali 'LC , LSC LIC' pra pegar um id ou classname e da um estilo pra ele com z-index menor que 9999